# Font TimesTen in latex

Tags: fonts

This is an image representing a part of a page of a book

[image]

and this are two screenshots showing the fonts used in the PDF of the book

[image][image]

Someone know if and how is it possible to use these or similar fonts in latex?
Thank you

Comment: I think the math font is [mtpro2](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html), which has a lite version and a complete version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Stephen's guess that the math font that's in use in the screenshot is [MathTime Professional II](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font, short `mtpro2`. A convincing clue is provided by the shape of the letter `v` ("vee") in various formulas. The MathTime Professional II fonts were created by the late [Michael Spivak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Spivak), author of the five-volume *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*.

Unfortunately, the `mtpro2` font package is commercial, i.e., it isn't free of charge. (The `lite` subset of the `mtpro2` package is free of charge; however, it may not suffice for all of the math material *you* may need to typeset.) I suggest you look into using the `newtxmath` package for a Times Roman-style math font that's included in all modern TeX distributions.

For the following screenshot, which replicates two of the displayed formulas in the OP's query, I chose to use `\upsilon` rather than `v`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'gather*' env.
\usepackage{newtxtext}  % Times Roman clone text font package
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} 
\usepackage{newtxmath}  % Times Roman clone math font package

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\int_{\hat{\phi}-\delta}^{\hat{\phi}+\delta}
  \frac{\phi-\hat{\phi}}{2 \upsilon_L G(\phi-\hat{\phi}\mkern1mu)^2
  +\upsilon_L^2-\upsilon^2} \, d\phi = 0\,. \\[2\jot]
\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{S}_2(\upsilon)\mathbf{b}=\frac{1}{\pi}
  \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{1}{\rho} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
  \frac{(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a}_i(\phi))^2}{%
  c_i(\phi)^2 -\upsilon^2\cos^2\phi} \, d\phi\,.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that the font is available on CTAN, but it is not easy for me (as a tex dummy) to install it. Thank you anyway